# File referencing issue over a connection to server

Tags: auxiliary-files

I am working on a system where access to my LaTeX files/header.tex/even JPG files I created to insert in my LaTeX documents … is all on a work drive.

Within a given LaTeX document, I’d normally write something like:

```
\includegraphics{L:/3d.jpg}
```

But this employee work L-drive storage is only set up to be directly accessible on Windows PCs, and I’m working with TeXShop on my Mac.  I can connect to these same files using “connect to server” on my Mac, and when I click ‘get info’ for the file in question, I see its reference as: `smb://companyX-storage/home/myname/3d.jpg`

So, I tried inserting:

```
\includegraphics{smb://companyX-storage/home/myname/3d.jpg}
```

But this LaTeX file wouldn’t compile, meaning it wasn’t the reference TeXShop was expecting. Do you have a helpful pointer in how I can include such files over this connection to the server, instead of copying them over to the local MacBook HDD storage?

Comment: you should be able to make a symbolic link  `L:` on the mac that points to `smb://companyX-storage/home/myname`  then your first form would work (I think, I don't have a mac but that would work from a similar linux windows mount)

Comment: Thanks…I tried exactly this, but when I tried to compile my LaTeX…I got an error for trying to use “L:/head.tex” …

Comment: I finally tried “/Volumes/home/myname/head.tex” and that’s exactly what worked in my setup to use the network stored file but not have to copy it over to my local Mac hdd